# Mercurial - merging last three unpushed commits

Tags: version-control, merge, mercurial, commit, tortoisehg

I have (locally) three hg commits. As two of them are basically but a couple of minor corrections, I would like to merge them into a single commit prior to pushing.

Any way to do that (with TortoiseHg or console)?

Comment: Use `hg histedit`. Works like a charm.

Comment: Am I overlooking that in the UI or will I have to use the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the 'histedit' extension for this.
To activate it, add the following to your hgrc:

```
[extensions]
histedit =
```

If these are the only unpushed changesets, you can use `hg histedit --outgoing`.

Once in the histedit interface, 'fold' will be a useful action for you (it allows combining your changesets).